# Special Characters Validation Not Working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to apply Regular Expression Validation to a textbox User Control and it's only working when I enter something at the end of the text in the textbox. And when I type something somewhere in the middle of the text, it's not working.

For Example: Hey Man! (When I type '!' at the end of the text, my Code's working fine)
             Hey! Man! (But when I insert '!' somewhere in the middle of the text after the entire text is typed, not working)

Below is my Code:

```
$("textarea[id$=<%= TxtValue.ClientID %>]").keyup(function () {
            var txt = $(this).val();
            var regex = new RegExp('[^0-9a-zA-Z-,_.\:\s]+$');
            var vldttxt = regex.test(txt);
            if (txt.length > 0 && vldttxt === true) {
                alert("Error");
            }
            var noSpclChar = txt.replace(regex, "");
            this.value = noSpclChar;
        });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Your regex should be created with `var regex = /[^0-9a-zA-Z-,_.\:\s]+$/;`. On top of that, as written it matches a sequence of one or more "special" characters that preceed the end of the string; that's what the final `$` does. If you take that out, it'll match special characters anywhere in the target string.

Comment: @Pointy Wow! You're the man! It works. I'm having a tiny issue now. When I type something in the middle, the code's working fine but the Cursor is moving away to the end of the text. Any idea why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: It happens because your code always resets the `.value` property of the element. You could change it so that that only is done when there's a validation problem.

Comment: @Pointy How would I do that? I must reset the element's value right? to remove the Special Characters from the text.

Comment: Yes but you don't have to do that if no special characters are found. If they are, well there are ways of manipulating the cursor position but it's not a thing I'm familiar with offhand.

Comment: @Pointy Oh. Okay. Thanks for the tip anyway ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Your ending $ is what is keeping it from matching anything within the string:

```
$("textarea[id$=<%= TxtValue.ClientID %>]").keyup(function () {
            var txt = $(this).val();
            var regex = new RegExp('[^0-9a-zA-Z-,_.\:\s]+');
            var vldttxt = regex.test(txt);
            if (txt.length > 0 && vldttxt === true) {
                alert("Error");
            }
            var noSpclChar = txt.replace(regex, "");
            this.value = noSpclChar;
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the instant response kowie le roux. It works now. The issue that I'm facing now is when I type something in the middle, the Code's working fine, but the Cursor is moving away to the end of the text. Any idea why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: It is most probably the browser behavior when replacing text when you do this.value = noSpclChar. Replacing text is like swapping the entire line for something new, because it's new, and contains text, the cursor moves to the end. Nothing I can think of to fix this other than calling the "no special character" function on form submit instead of key up

Answer (score 1):

**> Most simple code ....Special Characters Validation**

```
  function checkForm(theForm) {
     var result = /^[a-z0-9\\.;,:'\\s]{1,100}$/i(theForm.data.value);

     if (!result) {
        alert("No legal characters entered");
     }

     return !!result;
  }
```

Comment: That's some neat Code! Thanks Sai Narasimha Tech!